# NServiceBus throws "No endpoint configuration found" error due to Fluent NHibernate ClassMap

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, nservicebus

I have an NServiceBus 3.0 endpoint set up to use FluentNHibernate as my ORM and when I start the endpoint, I receive the awesome "No endpoint configuration found in scanned assemblies. This usually happens when NServiceBus fails to load your assembly containing IConfigureThisEndpoint" error message.

I tried just using a hibernate xml class map, and that worked fine. Also, I have an endpoint using NServiceBus 2.6 that uses Fluent Nhibernate and works just fine.

I would really like to stick with NSB V3 because I am using Raven Saga Persistence and I don't want to write Nhibernate xml files if I can help it. Does anyone know the solution to this issue?

Edit: Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/2965666/%22gist%22) to reproduce the issue. The endpoint starts just fine if you comment out the class FooMapping.

Comment: Why do you need FluentNHibernate if you are going to use the RavenSagaPersister? Do you have any inner exception?

Comment: I'm also interacting with a relational database during the saga. I use fluent to build out the domain objects.

Comment: Are any of the assemblies blocked?  This may mess up the scanning process.

Comment: NSB shouldn't be involved unless you're referencing the nsb.nhibernate.dll?

Comment: No assemblies are blocked. Also, nsb.nhibernate is not referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has the same issue before there is a fix, the problem was that I added FluentNhibernate via NuGet. That caused NHibernate 3.3.1.400 to be added also. However, FluentNHibernate was internally referencing NHibernate 3.3.0.400.

The solution I used was to downgrade NHibernate to 3.3.0.4000.